# Can't push file to SD card using Eclipse emulator

Tags: android

I'm trying to push a 3GP file to the Eclipse emulator.  I open the emulator and in Eclipse go to the DDMS perspective. In File Explorer, I open /mnt and highlight sdcard.  I click on the "Push a file onto the device" button and choose my 3GP file.  Nothing happens.  I don't get an error message, but I don't see my file under sdcard either.  Any ideas why this is happening?  The permissions on the sdcard are d---rwxr-x.

Does it matter that the 3GP file is also in my project under the raw folder?  Just a shot in the dark...

Any ideas/suggestions are most welcome.  Thank you!

Comment: When you made the emulator, did you give it space for an SD card, and give it the hardware property for having an SD card?

Comment: Make sure you have a mounted sdcard

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this?

Go to `platform-tools` dir

run `cmd`

```
adb push yourfile.3gp \sdcard\target_folder
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't have a platform-tools directory. I'm running Eclipse Release 2.  Is it called something different in that release?

Comment: Oops - sorry, I _DO_ have a platform-tools directory.  For some reason, it didn't show up when I searched for it, but it is there.  Sorry, I'm a total Android noob.  Anyway, when I try your suggestion, I get "failed to copy 'myfile.3gp' to '\sdcard': Read-only file system.